# UnityBootstrapper RegisterTypesIfMissing when types reside in assemblies that are not refrenced

Tags: unity-container, prism

I am struggling to *register concrete implementation* of *an interface in a Prism application* when the assembly that contains the implementing type is not referenced. It is fine if this can be done through configuration.

Consider this *code*:

```
RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IHostData), NOT_REFERENCED_ASSEMBLY_TYPE, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you look at Unity's [registration by convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.allclasses_members(v=pandp.30).aspx) ability.  Specifically, the [AllClasses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.allclasses_members(v=pandp.30).aspx) helper allows you to locate types within an assembly or many assemblies to register.  You could use reflection to load the assembly and pass it to this helper, or you could use the [AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.allclasses.fromassembliesinbasepath(v=pandp.30).aspx) method to have Unity load the assembly for you.  Also take a look at [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx).